# Non Diagonal elements from non square array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following dateframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'month':['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'], 'Tonnes':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]})
```

Need diagonal correlation Matrix that only has non diagonal elements.
Tried guided by past posts but all look into `nxn` array

Expected output:

```
columns = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
index= ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
data=np.array([[ 'nan', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'X'],
       [ 'X', 'nan', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'X', 'X'],
       [ 'X', 'X', 'nan', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'X'],
       [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'nan', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'X'],
       [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'nan', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'X'],
       [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'nan', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'X'],
       [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'nan', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'X'],
       [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'nan', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'X'],
       [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'nan', 'X',
        'X', 'X'],
       [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'nan', 'X',
        'X'],
       [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'nan', 'X'],
       [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X',
        'X', 'nan']])
matrix=pd.DataFrame(data,index=index,columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the non-diagonal elements with a boolean mask and reshaping:

```
data[~np.eye(len(data), dtype=bool)].reshape(len(data)-1, -1)
```

Comment: Applying to np array derived from dataframe returns; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-53b224b2ce99> in <module>
----> 1 data[~np.eye(len(data), dtype=bool)].reshape(len(data)-12, -12)

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 2 but corresponding boolean dimension is 12